# Вопрос про компиляцию php из исходников

Tags: php, компиляция

Привет всем. 
Если скомпилить исходники php с опцией `--enable-embed`, то создаются дин.библиотека `libphp5.so`.

У меня есть своё расширение (extension) для php, можно ли сделать так, чтобы скомпилить php вместе с моим расширением? Чтобы создался `libphp5.so`, в котором оно сидело бы внутри?

Comment: А зачем? Не проще ли создать свое расширение отдельно и подключать его как и остальные расширения?

Comment: Зачем это долгая история. Но так вышло, что нужно сделать именно так. Вариант с подключением как остальные расширения, к сожалению, не подходит